# How to move sections of XML with Ruby and Nokogiri between XML files

Tags: ruby, xml, git, nokogiri

I have a program that stores configuration data in a single XML file. The program is installed on two servers, production and dev. I want to move a piece of the XML file into a git repository and push it from dev to production.

The XML file has a section for each project so I only need the section for the project I’m working on. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Timers>
    <timer AUTOSTART="0" CONTAINER="" CONTAINER_PWD="" CONTAINER_USER="" LOG_ACTIVE="INFO" LOG_SIZE="25" MAXJOBS="10" MAXLOGSIZE="5000" NAME="OrderImports" OWNPROCESS="0" VMARGS="">
        <job DATE_REPEAT="0" DAY="0" DESCRIPTION="Send CertainTeed ShipFile - Once a day" DISABLE="0" FRI="1" HIGH_PRIORITY="0" HOUR="23" INTHOUR="" INTMIN="" INTSEC="" JOBID="66e6aa67-0ad0-4480-91ae-d17c3e769f4a" MIN="00" MON="1" MONTH="0" RUNONCE="0" SAT="0" SUN="0" THU="1" TIMEOUTHOUR="" TIMEOUTMIN="04" TIMEOUTSEC="" TOHOUR="" TOMIN="" TUE="1" WED="1" YEAR="0">
            <unit>order_imports.PutCertainTeedShipFile</unit>
        </job>
        <job DATE_REPEAT="0" DAY="0" DESCRIPTION="Send CertainTeed BudgetFile - Once a day" DISABLE="0" FRI="1" HIGH_PRIORITY="0" HOUR="22" INTHOUR="" INTMIN="" INTSEC="" JOBID="dca2f65a-08d8-4dd3-b663-ccaf4718c558" MIN="00" MON="1" MONTH="0" RUNONCE="0" SAT="0" SUN="0" THU="1" TIMEOUTHOUR="" TIMEOUTMIN="04" TIMEOUTSEC="" TOHOUR="" TOMIN="" TUE="1" WED="1" YEAR="0">
            <unit>order_imports.PutCertainTeedBudgetFile</unit>
        </job>
        <job DATE_REPEAT="0" DAY="0" DESCRIPTION="Send CertainTeed BudgetInvoice File - Once a day" DISABLE="0" FRI="1" HIGH_PRIORITY="0" HOUR="23" INTHOUR="" INTMIN="" INTSEC="" JOBID="12ccb8dd-1f06-4767-a86e-364fd5a4ff52" MIN="30" MON="1" MONTH="0" RUNONCE="0" SAT="0" SUN="0" THU="1" TIMEOUTHOUR="" TIMEOUTMIN="" TIMEOUTSEC="" TOHOUR="" TOMIN="" TUE="1" WED="1" YEAR="0">
            <unit>order_imports.PutCertainTeedBudgetInvoice</unit>
        </job>
        <job DATE_REPEAT="0" DAY="0" DESCRIPTION="Send CertainTeed Shiproof File - Once a day" DISABLE="0" FRI="1" HIGH_PRIORITY="0" HOUR="23" INTHOUR="" INTMIN="" INTSEC="" JOBID="6ba478a6-82aa-45c9-abb3-cde1429012fe" MIN="30" MON="1" MONTH="0" RUNONCE="0" SAT="0" SUN="0" THU="1" TIMEOUTHOUR="" TIMEOUTMIN="" TIMEOUTSEC="" TOHOUR="" TOMIN="" TUE="1" WED="1" YEAR="0">
            <unit>order_imports.PutCertainTeedShipFileRoof</unit>
        </job>
    </timer>
    <timer AUTOSTART="0" CONTAINER="" CONTAINER_PWD="" CONTAINER_USER="" LOG_ACTIVE="INFO" LOG_SIZE="25" MAXJOBS="10" MAXLOGSIZE="5000" NAME="CPC8" OWNPROCESS="0" VMARGS="">
        <job DATE_REPEAT="0" DAY="0" DESCRIPTION="CPC8" DISABLE="0" FRI="1" HIGH_PRIORITY="0" HOUR="05" INTHOUR="" INTMIN="02" INTSEC="" JOBID="804dfb35-d5a6-4075-b55c-328cf556da7c" MIN="00" MON="1" MONTH="0" RUNONCE="0" SAT="1" SUN="1" THU="1" TIMEOUTHOUR="" TIMEOUTMIN="" TIMEOUTSEC="" TOHOUR="01" TOMIN="30" TUE="1" WED="1" YEAR="0">
            <unit>cpc8.cpc8AvettiMain</unit>
        </job>
        <job DATE_REPEAT="0" DAY="0" DESCRIPTION="CPC82" DISABLE="0" FRI="1" HIGH_PRIORITY="0" HOUR="05" INTHOUR="" INTMIN="02" INTSEC="" JOBID="66cbe9a2-d79a-4cfd-9f21-b1c72f04aaa5" MIN="00" MON="1" MONTH="0" RUNONCE="0" SAT="1" SUN="1" THU="1" TIMEOUTHOUR="" TIMEOUTMIN="" TIMEOUTSEC="" TOHOUR="01" TOMIN="30" TUE="1" WED="1" YEAR="0">
            <unit>cpc8.cpc8AvettiMain2</unit>
        </job>
        <job DATE_REPEAT="0" DAY="0" DESCRIPTION="CPC8 Inbound Order Shop" DISABLE="0" FRI="1" HIGH_PRIORITY="0" HOUR="05" INTHOUR="" INTMIN="05" INTSEC="" JOBID="05fb0f4c-f175-4e10-a885-63d2aa07f2ef" MIN="00" MON="1" MONTH="0" RUNONCE="0" SAT="1" SUN="1" THU="1" TIMEOUTHOUR="" TIMEOUTMIN="" TIMEOUTSEC="" TOHOUR="01" TOMIN="30" TUE="1" WED="1" YEAR="0">
            <unit>cpc8.cpc8InboundLauncherDev2</unit>
        </job>
        <job DATE_REPEAT="0" DAY="0" DESCRIPTION="CPC8 Sync Journal Monitor" DISABLE="0" FRI="1" HIGH_PRIORITY="0" HOUR="07" INTHOUR="03" INTMIN="" INTSEC="" JOBID="8bb67c1a-6935-4069-8c04-48d53b678d75" MIN="00" MON="1" MONTH="0" RUNONCE="0" SAT="1" SUN="1" THU="1" TIMEOUTHOUR="" TIMEOUTMIN="" TIMEOUTSEC="" TOHOUR="22" TOMIN="" TUE="1" WED="1" YEAR="0">
            <unit>cpc8.syncMonitor</unit>
        </job>
    </timer>
```

This example contains two projects "OrderImports" and "CPC8". I need the "OrderImports" project, identified by the name attribute on the timer node.

I used a Ruby script with Nokogiri to parse the relevant information from the XML file. I’m using `to_xml` output and saving it to a file in the git repo.

Here is the code that will save it to a text file. How do I restore the node from this text file back to the original file?

```
    def find_timers_by_name
        timers = []
        nodes = @timer_noko.xpath("Timers/timer/job/unit[contains(text(), '#{@project_name}')]")
        nodes.each do |node|
            timers << node.parent.parent.attribute("NAME")
        end
        return timers.uniq
    end

    def dump_timer_xml
        timers = find_timers_by_name
        timer_dir = "./int_config/timers"
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(timer_dir)

        timers.each do |timer|
            nodes = @timer_noko.xpath("Timers/timer[@NAME='#{timer}']")
            nodes.each do |node|
                timer_xml_file = File.join(timer_dir, "#{timer}.xml")
                tx = "\t#{node.to_xml}"
                File.open(timer_xml_file, 'w') { |file| file.write(tx) }
            end
        end
    end
```

I would like to take it a step further and not replace the node unless something has actually changed or the node does not exist.

I need to have the script check to see if the project section exists in the main XML file and, if so, replace it with the one from the git repo.  I’m hoping that Nokogiri has some sort of built-in methods for doing this. I do not need to use `to_xml` if that’s not going to work.

Comment: If you are dealing with XML containing data, consider using a small database to read the data, then select only the records you want and emit those as XML. DBMs can do this easily these days, and they're the perfect candidate repository for breaking down huge data sets into small ones. It's possible to do so in memory using an XML parser but that's not really what they're designed for.

Comment: Also, as asked, it seems you want us to write the code for you, rather can fix the code you've written but not shared with us. Stack Overflow isn't a code generation source, but is instead to help you fix code. Care to share what you've written toward solving this problem?

Comment: I have updated the post to include the code I have so far. This is a proprietary IDE and I am unable to change the format things are stored in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swapping data between two XML files in sql script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382102/swapping-data-between-two-xml-files-in-sql-script)